# Paper,Rock,Scissors game (c#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm working on a simple paper,rock,scissors game (c#),I made everything except the part where the user can type (for example) yes or no and play again or quit.How can I do this?
This is my current code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Do you choose rock,paper or scissors");
            string userChoice = Console.ReadLine();

            Random r = new Random();
            int computerChoice = r.Next(4);

                if (computerChoice == 1)
                {
                    if (userChoice == "rock")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("The computer chose rock");
                        Console.WriteLine("It is a tie ");                     
                    }
                    else if (userChoice == "paper")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("The computer chose paper");
                        Console.WriteLine("It is a tie ");

                    }
                    else if (userChoice == "scissors")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("The computer chose scissors");
                        Console.WriteLine("It is a tie ");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You must choose rock,paper or scissors!");

                    }

                }

                else if (computerChoice == 2)
                {
                    if (userChoice == "rock")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("The computer chose paper");
                        Console.WriteLine("Sorry you lose,paper beat rock");

                    }
                    else if (userChoice == "paper")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("The computer chose scissors");
                        Console.WriteLine("Sorry you lose,scissors beat paper ");

                    }
                    else if (userChoice == "scissors")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("The computer chose rock");
                        Console.WriteLine("Sorry you lose,rock beats scissors");                       
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You must choose rock,paper or scissors!");        
                    }
                }
                else if (computerChoice == 3)
                {
                    if (userChoice == "rock")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("The computer chose scissors");
                        Console.WriteLine("You win,rock beats scissors");

                    }
                    else if (userChoice == "paper")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("The computer chose rock");
                        Console.WriteLine("You win,paper beats rock");

                    }
                    else if (userChoice == "scissors")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("The computer chose paper");
                        Console.WriteLine("You win,scissors beat paper");

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You must choose rock,paper or scissors!");

                    }

                }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Help!...

Answer (score 1):

Remove the last `ReadLine`, put the entire logic in a `while` block as follows:

```
bool keepPlaying = true;
while (keepPlaying) {
    //game logic here

    Console.WriteLine("New game? y/n");
    ConsoleKeyInfo cki = Console.ReadKey(); //wait for player to press a key
    keepPlaying = cki.KeyChar == 'y'; //continue only if y was pressed
}
```

Comment: Thank you,gonna try this method! :)))

Answer (score 1):

Hope this works for you.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool continuegame = false;
            Random r = new Random();
            int computerChoice;
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nDo you choose rock,paper or scissors");
                string userChoice = Console.ReadLine();
                computerChoice = r.Next(3);
                if (userChoice.ToLower().Equals("rock") || userChoice.ToLower().Equals("paper") || userChoice.ToLower().Equals("scissors"))
                {
                    if (computerChoice == 1)
                    {
                        ComputerChoicePaper(userChoice);
                    }
                    else if (computerChoice == 2)
                    {
                        ComputerChoicePaper(userChoice);
                    }
                    else if (computerChoice == 3)
                    {
                        ComputerChoicePaper(userChoice);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nInvalid Input !!! please enter valid input, rock paper scissors");
                }
                Console.WriteLine("\nDo you  want to continue? y/n");
                var enteredk = Console.ReadKey();
                //Console.();
                continuegame = enteredk.Key.ToString().ToLower() == "y";
            } while (continuegame);
        }

        public static void ComputerChoicePaper(string userSelection)
        {
            if (userSelection.Equals("rock")|| userSelection.Equals("scissors"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nComputer Choice paper");

               Console.WriteLine("You won!! Worray");

            }
            else if (userSelection.Equals("paper"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nComputer Choice {0} as well its, a draw :P", userSelection);
            }
        }
        public void ComputerChoiceRock(string userSelection)
        {
            if (userSelection.Equals("paper") ||  userSelection.Equals("scissors"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nComputer Choice rock");
                Console.WriteLine("\nYou lost!! Computer won");

            }
            else if (userSelection.Equals("rock"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nComputer Choice {0} as well its, a draw :P", userSelection);
            }
        }
        public void ComputerChoiceScissors(string userSelection)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nComputer Choice scissors");
            if (userSelection.Equals("rock"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nYou won!! Worray");

            }
            else if(userSelection.Equals("paper"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nYou lost!! Computer won");

            }
            else if (userSelection.Equals("scissors"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nComputer Choice {0} as well its, a draw :P", userSelection);
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap everything in a `do while` structure:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Do you choose rock,paper or scissors");
            string userChoice = Console.ReadLine();
            // Rest of your code
        }while(Console.ReadLine() == "yes");
    }
}
```

This will execute your code once, and then once again every time the user inputs `yes`.

With that, you don't need any private variables and you'll be sure the game will be executed at least once. If you want to prompt the user (something alone the lines of "play again?"), you can do so at the end of your existing code, before the `}while` part.

Comment: Thanks,I'm gonna try it! :)))

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, when you call `r.Next(4);` you program has a chance to generate a number from 0 to 3. So the possibilities `computerChoice` for are 0, 1, 2, 3... Your program does not have any code handling a `computerChoice` when it is equal to 0 so it just abruptly closes. To solve this first change `r.Next(4);` to `r.Next(3);` which will give the possibilities of 0, 1, 2. Just change `else if (computerChoice == 3)` to `else if (computerChoice == 0)'. This will fix your program. Secondly, as the other answers have said it would be wise to put a loop around your entire program so you can play RPS multiple times.

-mnursey